# Image<,> won't dispose using EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, memory-leaks, memory-consumption, emgucv

This question was asked by **a lot** but none answered!
I am using EmguCV, the OpenCV wrapper for .NET. I am disposing all created objects but my app is still using more and more memory till it crashes.
I nearly tried everything, including: `.Dispose()` `=null` `using()`
and even GC was running nearly every half a second, nothing did work!
Here's my code:

(I have selected 100 scanned images, all of JPG type and 300dpi)
One of these images is uploaded to DropBox in order to preserve quality:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsbe8pesbxk7dsz/Example.jpg?dl=0

```
private void OpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        open.Multiselect = true;
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            for (int i = 0; i < open.FileNames.Count(); i++)
                using (Image<Bgr, byte> ToProcess = new Image<Bgr, byte>(open.FileNames[i]))
                    ProcessImage (ToProcess);
    }
}

private void ProcessImage (Image<Bgr, byte> imgInput)
{
    imgInput._SmoothGaussian(5);            
}
```

Also I tried to update the code inside `ProcessImage` Function to the following, but my program freezes and crashes!

```
IntPtr image = imgInput;
imgInput._SmoothGaussian(5);
CvInvoke.cvReleaseImage(ref image);
```

**Important Update:** *if the function  finishes before my program crashes, surprisingly it will release All of the memory. Here is a graph.*

[image: Ram going up]

I am using VS 2017-Community, Win10 64-bit, both up to date, and last stable version of EmguCV 3.4.3

Comment: There seems to be a lot of context missing here... provide a proper [MCVE]. One thing you definitely should show is how exactly you're "sending about 100 images to the following function".

Comment: @DanMašek Hi, I followed your advice. Hope you could help now and thanks.

Comment: What's `ProcessImageStage1`? Some kind of asynchronous dispatch of `ProcessImage`? My first wild guess (due to the lack of info, plus I'm no C# expert) would be that you load the images much faster than the thread pool can process them... but hard to say without seeing everything involved (hence the request for [mcve]) -- it might not be me who solves this, but what I'm asking for is the generic sort of information that you need to know to have any hope to solve the problem.

Comment: @DanMašek I have updated my post. Also, I was able to solve most of the Ram issue by using a backgroundworker to process those images instead of a traditional function. could you help me understand why this was helpful...

Comment: I don't really know enough about the internals of the modern C# (I primarily deal with C++) to give you a good explanation. I'd guess that the for loop with `using` somehow prevented the images from being deallocated immediately after they were used. You could try to load the image in the function that uses it, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have the same problem as you with Windows 10, Emgu 3.4.3 and I solved it by explicitly call `GC.Collect()`. Maybe you should call it inside the for loop.

Comment: It didn't work, Also you shouldn't force GC to run, it's not rec commend